# Dockerfile for nginx + php7 + AWS EFS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-efs

I use my following code:
https://github.com/fabbi94/test-docker

The docker build and run without any problem,  but I get a 502 Bad Gateway error when I go to localhost.

Also, I'd like to add my AWS EFS drive as **"/www"** that all container uses the same code (because I will run more than one). I have the URL/DNS for the drive, but how can I mount them to the **"/www"** drive? I use local files like in the Dockerfile **"COPY /src /www"** that should be replaced by the AWS EFS drive.

Comment: Why don't you create a Docker image with your PHP source code and run the image multiple times? Using AWS EFS for this doesn't seem very logical nor beneficial.

Comment: Because user can upload images to it and so all changes are only in one docker and not in the other ones. In addition when one container get shut down all changes to code get lost. That is the reason why I like to use EFS.